# Xampp & Tomcat button in control panel is disabled

Tags: tomcat, xampp

Tomcat **Start** button  disabled in  XAMPP Control Panel. I only can run it from  taskbar overflow icon, so sad and a little bit wasting of energy.

How can i enable the button in XAMPP control panel? Tomcat is fine with running from the Taskbar icon, but only in Control Panel the button is not enabled, thanks in advance!!!!

[image: screen shot of control panel]

Answer (score 1):

I recently had this issue with the recent PHP 7.4.28 and PHP 8.1.4 releases which were released a few days go (18th March 2022)

In my case Tomcat had been updated to Tomcat 10.0.17 within the latest xampp releases, in a file called xampp-control.ini it was referencing to the old version (tomcat8.exe)

The fix that worked in my instance was changing a line of code within a file called xampp-control.ini

[xampp-control.ini Filename Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vzzNv.png)

What I did was open up xampp/xampp-control.ini in a text editor, found the following section

```
[BinaryNames]
Apache=httpd.exe
MySQL=mysqld.exe
FileZilla=filezillaserver.exe
FileZillaAdmin=filezilla server interface.exe
Mercury=mercury.exe
Tomcat=tomcat8.exe
```

and replaced the line Tomcat=tomcat8.exe with Tomcat=tomcat10.exe so the section now looks like the following

```
[BinaryNames]
Apache=httpd.exe
MySQL=mysqld.exe
FileZilla=filezillaserver.exe
FileZillaAdmin=filezilla server interface.exe
Mercury=mercury.exe
Tomcat=tomcat10.exe
```

I then saved the changed file, closed and restart the xampp control panel

I found my Tomcat version / filename within xampp\tomcat\bin folder

[Tomcat Filename Location](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r71ZP.png)

Comment: thanks, I will try this method later. And skomisa user edited my question with his “THE”!!! I want to ask questions in my way, don't you dare to edit again!!! If you are so brilliant go edit yours/